# Making a function wait a certain amount of time before it executes in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I know this question has been asked before, but I could not find one for pygame. I have a coin power-up that increases my points by 5000 every time it is picked up. However, as soon as I pick up the coin, another one appears. I don't want it to appear for another 30 seconds. How can this be accomplished without pausing the entire program?

```
if coin.collidepoint(x,y):
    points+=5000
    coin=makecoin()
```

Comment: Almost impossible to answer without more information about the architecture of your program.

Comment: Have you considered using using a Timer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/), you have built in functions.

[pygame.time.get_ticks()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) get time in milliseconds
[pygame.time.set_timer()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) set repeating timer.

Answer (score 0):

Your game has a main loop.  When you pick up a coin you should save the time that you picked it up and set `coin = None`, then in that main loop you should have something like the following:

```
if coin is None and current_time > coin_picked_up + 30:
    coin = makecoin()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a timer. It should be as simple as that.

```
from threading import Timer

if coin.collidepoint(x,y):
    points+=5000
    t = Timer(30.0, makecoin)
    t.start()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When my player goes over the coin, it just constantly increases in points by intervals of 5000.

Comment: @Andre did you remove the coin when the player moves over it?

Comment: Well the coin is put into a function, and every time that function is executed, it creates a new x and y point for the coin, so by creating new points, I am technically removing the coin.

Comment: Oh, so your coin is not something like a class? You just blit each coin per frame and check the collision? Hmmm. I would recommend objects, but if you must... You need a way to skip the collision check and coin draw once you pass over it (do this with what ever you feel comfortable with). Then the timer needs to enable it again with the timed out function.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) module. You could use this to defer the creation of the new coin.

Assuming that you have a scheduler called s, defined as follows (just like the example in the Python manual)...

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
```

Then you'd schedule your coin to be created like this...

```
if coin.collidepoint(x,y):
    points+=5000
    s.enter(30, 1, make_coin, ())
```

And you'd call s.run() periodically to run anything that is due to be run. It is unlikely that you will need to call it on every tick unless you really need fine grained timing.